# Amazon Face Recognition error in POSTMAN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, postman, face-recognition

I want to integrate **Amazon Rekognition** for the Face Recognition.

I have created bucket and IAM user. I am trying to hit ***"RekognitionService.ListCollections"*** for the testing in POSTMAN but getting error as follows;

> ```
>  <InvalidSignatureException>   <Message>Credential should be scoped to
>  correct service: 'rekognition'. </Message>
>  </InvalidSignatureException>
> ```

My request header is as follows;

```
https://rekognition.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/

x-amz-content-sha256:STREAMING-AWS4-HMAC-SHA256-PAYLOAD
X-Amz-Target:RekognitionService.ListCollections
X-Amz-Date:20180130T123032Z
Host:rekognition.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Content-Length:142
Authorization:AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=XXXXXXXXXX/20180130/us-east-2/RekognitionService.ListCollections/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=accept-encoding;content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=xxxxxxxxxxx
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accept-Encoding:identity
```

Can anyone please guide me how to test AWS apis in POSTMAN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your `Accesskey`,`SecretKey` and service name as `rekognition`  in AWS singature

[image]

Add empty `JSON` like `{}` in body parameter as `raw`.

After updating request your header look like this

[image]

> Add new header `X-Amz-Target` value as `RekognitionService.ListCollections` and `Content-Type` as `application/x-amz-json-1.1`